# iAd ad showing frequency

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iad, ads

I have been experimenting with iAd today in an app I am planning to release in the next few hours. I think it works as it should, however I have played my app for over 20 minutes and not a single test ad has shown. The methods that are responsible for showing the ads have been break-pointed so I know when an ad attempts to fire. Does apple control when the ads are shown? Is the frequency that the ads are shown random; or do apps only show an ad a number of times and then stop showing them? I haven't been able to find any documentation that describes when ads are shown in apps. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: iAD's only show up in certain regions. Maybe you aren't in one of them? Also, look into Apple's iADSuite for sample code, as you may be doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have imported  iAdFramework and in your .h file don't forget to import iAd/iAd.h
also it has a delegate method ADBannerViewDelegate

In Your .h file do this     ADBannerView *bannerView;

// In your .m file

```
-(void)AddBanner

 {

    bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc]
              initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
bannerView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers =
[NSSet setWithObjects:
 ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait,
 ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape, nil];
bannerView.delegate = self;

  }

  - (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
   {
   NSLog(@"banner didload");
   [self.view addSubview:bannerView];

    }


 - (BOOL)bannerViewActionShouldBegin: (ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave

   {
    return YES;
    }

   - (void)bannerViewActionDidFinish:(ADBannerView *)banner

   {

     NSLog(@"bannerViewActionDidFinish");

    }

  - (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error

   {

     NSLog(@"bannerView Error occureed");

    }


in your

  -(void)viewDidLoad

  {


 [self AddBanner];

   }
```

hope, this will help you.

Comment: I think what I meant to ask was, 'how often does apple send iAd requests to a user of an app?' The implementation of the iAd framework was fine in my app, I was simply wondering how often ads are displayed while playing the game. Every now and then an ad shows up, but long amounts of time can pass before another shows up.